# Custom jquery Carousel for HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, jcarousel

I am looking for Jquery Carousel with control - Play/Pause, Next, Previous and a slider control(range) to drag the slide(next and previous).

Please suggest me some example and demos.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: uhm, am I missing something or what exactly is HTML5 about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like this carousel http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

It doesn't have a slider built in, so you'll have to integrate your own, which should be trivial. I suggest this one http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

Answer (score 0):

Best customisable jQuery lib that I found several years ago is jQuery Tools. Still using it. It's better than jQuery UI, more decoupled from stylesheets and have a better API, and yep, it's in the GitHub :)

Look for the documentation, examples and other related stuff at http://flowplayer.org/tools/